# Web pricing scraper, creating URL loop

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to create a web scraper that gets pricing from URLs in column B.

I'd like a loop so that the price from the HTML will be extracted to column C.

My code gives an "Automation Error'.

My code works without the loop, when I specify a cell as "range" but I don't want to repeat the code 50 times.

I have hidden the 'ClassName' for privacy reasons.

```vb
Sub FetchPrices_data()

    Dim Model As String
    Dim request As Object
    Dim response As String
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim Price As String
    Dim i As Integer
    
    For i = 1 To 50
    
        Model = Range("B" & i).Value
        
        Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        
        request.Open "GET", Model, False
        
        request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        
        request.send
        
        response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)
            
        html.body.innerHTML = response
            
        Price = html.getElementsByClassName(" Hidden ").Item(0).innerText
                
        Range("C" & i).Value = Price
    
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Move out of the loop the part where you create the object, you don't need to create 50 times that. Also, try debugging your code step by step with F8 and see the exact loop where it fails. ¿Maybe a wrong value of `Model`?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the tips! It's now solved.
I added an error indicator as well.
Here is what I did to solve the issue:

```
Sub FetchPrices_data()

    Dim Model As String
    Dim request As Object
    Dim response As String
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim Price As String
    Dim i As Integer
    
    For i = 2 To 35        
        Model = Range("B" & i).Value
        
        Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        
        If request Is Nothing Then
            Range("B" & i).Value = "URL Error."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        request.Open "GET", Model, False
        
        request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        
        request.send
        
        response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)
            
        html.body.innerHTML = response
            
        If Not html.getElementsByClassName(" *Hidden* ").Item(0) Is Nothing Then
            Price = html.getElementsByClassName(" *Hidden* ").Item(0).innerText
            Range("C" & i).Value = Price
        Else
            Range("C" & i).Value = "URL Error"
        End If                                                        
    Next i        
End Sub
```